# Save Memory when Loading Collection View

Tags: swift, firebase, memory, google-cloud-firestore

How would I go about saving memory when loading items into a collection view from a database? Suppose I have over 10,000 items in a database that is being retrieved (including images) into a collection view with multiple labels also being retrieved from the database.

Would I have to retrieve only the first 20-50 items and then create a function to retrieve the next set when the user has passed through the data or would it have more to do with the images?

Comment: While there is an accepted and very good answer, the bigger question is why are you loading 10,000 items at one time in the first place? That's not going to be a really good user experience - consider loading 15-20 items and *paginate* as the user scrolls through them.There'a bunch of posts here on SO as well as a couple of snappy YouTube videos that cover the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 10, you can [prefetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data?language=objc) data via the `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol.

I would encourage you to download the sample and have a play around but essentially it allows you to:

- fetch data before it's needed on screen.
- load data asynchronously.
- cancel unnecessary fetches.

In terms of memory concerns, both table views and collection views employ object pooling to reuse cell views, populating them with new data.

More specifically this is achieved by calling [dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell) within your implementation of the `UICollectionViewDataSource` method [collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview)

An example of that is something along the lines of:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Dequeues an existing cell if one is available, 
    // or creates a new one based on the registered class/nib.
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? Cell else {
        fatalError("Expected `\(Cell.self)` type for reuseIdentifier \(Cell.reuseIdentifier). Check the configuration in Main.storyboard.")
    }
    // Configure the cell for display.
    return cell
}
```

Happy coding :D

Comment: Thank you so much! Extremely informative and helpful! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the data only when need. Core Data already has this ready for you. Take a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Great. Thank you!