# Save memory when retrieving firebase object

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I have a FoodProduct object in Firebase and I wrote a search function in my app, that's how I get the products from the database:

```
fun getProductByName(name: String, callback: (FoodProduct?) -> Unit) {
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("")
    val reference = database.getReference("FoodProducts")

    // Query to get the food product for the specified ID
    val query = reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(name)

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val product = dataSnapshot.children.firstOrNull()?.getValue(FoodProduct::class.java)
            callback(product)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // Handle errors (if any)
            callback(null)
        }
    })
}`
```

`

```
 var searchQuery by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var searchResult by remember { mutableStateOf<List<FoodProduct>>(emptyList()) }

    LaunchedEffect(searchQuery) {
        // Clear previous search results when the query changes
        searchResult = emptyList()

        getProductByName(searchQuery.toString()) { product ->
            product?.let {
                searchResult += listOf(it)
            }
        }
    }
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(searchResult) { product ->
                FoodProductItem(product = product, navController = navController)
            }
        }
```

If I have hundreds of products, the app becomes very slow, how can I optimize it to load for example 10 products, and when the user scrolls down another 10?

I tried limiting page size and page indexes but it's difficult with the data I get from Firebase.

I noted this question and I'm wondering how to implement it in my case: [Save Memory when Loading Collection View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830563/save-memory-when-loading-collection-view)

Comment: Have you thought about limiting the amount of items in the lazyColumn? And then based on the user's scroll behavior loading more items (also a limited amount)

Comment: @tomerpacific  I tried this:                 if (LazyListLayoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index == searchResult.lastIndex) {
                    loadingMore = true
                } But I get  Unresolved reference: visibleItemsInfo

Comment: @Tevel - what version of androidx.compose.foundation:foundation are you using?

Comment: @tomerpacific implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.4") and stay safe in Israel!

Comment: Have you thought about using the [take](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html) method on the searchResult list?

Comment: @tomerpacific yeah but if I have hundreds of products how will I know which ones to take if i only fetch 10 at a time?

Comment: Monitoring the scroll behavior and based on that add the appropriate amount of items each time (I.E. 3). That way, when you get to a point where you have no more items (or are close to not having more items), you fetch for more.

Comment: @tomerpacific can you help me figure out the code because I really break my head here

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-realtime-database-using-jetpack-compose-bd49084c8fd4) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabasePaginationJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks but I need to pay for medium account in order to view it.

Comment: You can check the repo. That's why I provided you the link of the GitHub repo.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm having a hard time finding what I need in this code, can you help me implement it to my code?

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer/repo and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: @AlexMamo But I try and try and I fail instead of just pointing to me the code in your project that looks like mine, please i will appreciate it!

Comment: @AlexMamo I try with this file but I don't know how to implement it: https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabasePaginationJetpackCompose/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/realtimedatabasepaginationjetpackcompose/data/paging/ProductsPagingSource.kt

Answer (score 0):

> If I have hundreds of products, the app becomes very slow

That's the expected behavior since you try to load so much data. At some point in time, you might also get an OutOfMemoryException when the data that you get from the Realtime Database cannot fit into the memory.

> How can I optimize it to load for example 10 products and when the user scrolls down another 10?

What you're looking for is called pagination. This means that you'll be able to load the data in smaller chunks.

So your app doesn't behave slowly because of the `LazyColumn` but because of the amount of data you get. So always try to limit the data that you get, so you can also avoid higher bills.

---

**P.S.** Since you're using Kotlin, try to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html) rather than callbacks. So I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/RealtimeDatabase).

Comment: Hey Tevel. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?